# Incorrect value - Looping Servicecalls in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-observable

I'm trying to get value of `this.totalbuilds_overview_jaas` which will update after every service call. Below is the code

```
constructor(private dataservice: CicdDashboardApiService) {   }

  calculating_jaas_builds_count(){
     var counter:number = 0;
    console.log("calculating jaas total builds..")
    this.jaasclients.forEach(element => {
      this.dataservice.getTotalBuildCounts_jaas(element.url,element.token).subscribe((response: TotalBuilds[]) => {
      counter = this.total_getObject_jaas(response['jobs'])
      this.totalbuilds_overview_jaas += counter
     },err => console.log(err))
    })
  }
```

The problem is - this.totalbuilds_overview_jaas not giving constant value. It keeps varying when I reload the application. How can I make necessary changes to load `this.totalbuilds_overview_jaas` only after completing the loop.

*this.total_getObject_jaas(response['jobs']) => returns some number

Comment: can you share your data service or please try refereing to rxjs forkjoin

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that you don't really know when the calls to `CicdDashboardApiService` will actually be complete at the time of retrieving `this.totalbuilds_overview_jaas` because `calculating_jaas_builds_count()` is actually asynchronous.

You need to wait for all the service requests to complete before you can get the total count. One way of doing it is simply with promises:

```js
  async calculating_jaas_builds_count() {
    console.log("calculating jaas total builds..");

    // Execute a data service request for each of the clients
    const promises = this.jaasclients.map(element =>
      this.dataservice
        .getTotalBuildCounts_jaas(element.url, element.token)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .toPromise()
    );

    // Wait for all requests to complete
    const responses = await Promise.all(promises);

    // Process each of the service responses and collect the jobs
    for (const response of responses) {
      this.totalbuilds_overview_jaas += response["jobs"];
    }
  }
```

You can then await this method and only then you can get the total count:

```js
await calculating_jaas_builds_count();
console.log('total count', this.totalbuilds_overview_jaas)
```

I'm not 100% sure about the structure of your service response because your typings say the response is an array of TotalBuilds, but on the next line you say `response['jobs']`, which seems like a mistake in itself. In any case, hope you get the idea.

Comment: where can I call? `await calculating_jaas_builds_count();` from ngOnit()?

Comment: That's for you to decide, I have no idea how you use that value in your app. `ngOnInit` can be async and you can await promises inside of it, but note that Angular will not delay the initialization of the component. The promise from ngOnInit will simply be ignored. However, if you are trying to display the count in a component, then I would suggest a completely different approach and making `this.totalbuilds_overview_jaas` an Observable and then binding to it with an `async` pipe in your component.Then you can pipe `this.jaasclients` into `this.totalbuilds_overview_jaas` using RXJS operators